# Not able to connect with tcp ip - server client program in linux using C programming

Tags: c, tcp

> This is my tcp_server code , please correct me of i am wrong. Problem is i am not able to connect.

```
        int  tcp_server(unsigned int uiPort, unsigned int MaxConnect) 
       {
        #define MAX_SOCKETS 1000
        int isocket = -1;
        struct sockaddr_in  servaddr;
        tcp_init();
        if (MaxConnect == 0)
        MaxConnect = MAX_SOCKETS;
        isocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (isocket >= 0){
         memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));    
         servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;    
         servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    
         servaddr.sin_port = htons(uiPort);    
         if( bind(isocket, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,   sizeof(servaddr)) == -1){
            tcp_close(isocket);
            isocket = -2;
         }else if( listen(isocket,MaxConnect ) == -1){
            tcp_close(isocket);
            isocket = -3;
         }
        }       
        return isocket;
        }
```

Comment: is connect call in the CLient side is failing ?

Comment: Simply compare to this http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W01.176B/hw2/examples/tcp-server.c

Answer (score 0):

Where you have accepted client socket.

```
SOCKET cli_addr;
size_t len = sizeof(cli_addr);
newsockfd = accept(servaddr, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, 
                                &clilen);
```

Then on `newsockfd` you need to do read/write operation.

You may refer to my tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvcUVYC46mU. But tutorial is about WinSock.

Comment: sir, how to connect , i tried different methods but it is not connected